# Debug Assertion Fail (vector subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, assertion

I found that my `result.push_back(make_pair(a[i], b[j]));`, which
causing this error but i dont know why (i don't even access  `vector<pair<int,int>>result;`)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
void input(int n,vector<int>&a) {
    int temps;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> temps;
        a.push_back(temps);
    }
}
int main() {
    //input
    long n, m;
    cin >> n; //6
    vector<int>a, b;
    input(n, a); //{2 5 4 1 7 5}
    cin >> m; //7
    input(m, b); //{2 3 1 3 2 4 6}
    //algorithm
    long max = *max_element(a.begin(), a.end()) + *max_element(b.begin(), b.end());
    long min = *min_element(a.begin(), a.end()) + *min_element(b.begin(), b.end());
    vector<pair<int, int>>result;
    int possible = max, plate = 0; 
    for (int check = max; check >= min; check--) {
        int j = 0, i = 0, plate2 = 0;
        for (; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a[i] >= check) {}
            else {
                if (j > b.size() - 1) { break; }
                if (a[i] + b[j] >= check) {
                    j++; plate2++;
                    result.push_back(make_pair(a[i], b[j]));
                }
                else {
                    i--; j++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > a.size() - 1) { possible = check; plate = plate2; break; } 
    }
    cout << possible << " " << plate << endl; //5 3 
    return 0;
 }
```

if you remove the line `result.push_back(make_pair(a[i],b[j]);`, there is no error message anymore, so i think i'm not access wrong a[i] and b[j] elements

Comment: *but i dont know why* -- If the runtime tells you that the subscript is out-of-range, then the reason is that your expectations are not what you thought they were, and your program has one or more bug(s) causing the indices to go out-of-bounds.  The next step is for you to debug your code to see why your logic is incorrect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh my , tks you , i just realize i put the wrong flow, it should be put before 'j++;'

Comment: If this is Visual Studio have the debugger break on this assertion and then when it breaks change the "Stack Frame" on the Debug toolbar to your code. Then inspect the variables to see what exact line is the problem and how you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (j > b.size() - 1) { break; }  //(1)
           if (a[i] + b[j] >= check) {  //(2)
               j++; plate2++;   // HERE IS YOUR PROBLEM (3)
               result.push_back(make_pair(a[i], b[j]));   //(4)
```

Assume that `j == b.size()-1` at the beginning. The `if (j > b.size() - 1)` clause is false, so the loop does not `break`. It continues with (2), which is okay. In (3) you add +1 to j, so now `j == b.size()`. In (4) you try to access `b[j]`, which is now `b[b.size()]`, which is invalid, as indizes start at 0.

IOW: You tried to assure that j never points beyond the number of valid elements, but then you increment j after that test and access invalid memory.

Comment: thank you very much, i have realized that. Btw, is there anyway to find exactly line which create assertion bug ? It's should have but i dont know where to use it

Comment: Use the "Callstack" window in the debugger. That'll show you exactly where the assert came from.